# Django CONN_MAX_AGE is set to 0 but connection remains open after executing query

Tags: django, postgresql, rds

I'm using Django 1.10 as an ORM connecting to a Postgres DB.
I have a problem where old connections stay open in `idle` state in the db.

My request is:

```py
MyTable.objects.all().first().id
```

I use the following query to verify that the connection remains open:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity  
WHERE usename = 'my_user_name'
ORDER BY backend_start DESC limit 3;
```

The result is:
[image]

This only disappears when i close my `ipython` or add `django.db.connection.close()` to my code.

According to `Django's` documentation, if MAX_CONN_AGE is set to default (0) the connection supposed to close after the end of the request, but its not closing as expected.

Answer (score 4):

It's really confusing, but "after the end of the request" in the docs means HTTP request, not the request to the database. Since there's no HTTP requests in the ipython session, connection stays idle. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#module-django.core.signals

Here's the place where connection close handlers are registered: [https://github.com/django/django/blob/21ff23bfeb4014bceaa3df27677fb68409c0634d/django/db/**init**.py#L60](https://github.com/django/django/blob/21ff23bfeb4014bceaa3df27677fb68409c0634d/django/db/__init__.py#L60)

If you want to close the connection after every request to the database you have to either find compromises with some other signal (`post_save`, for example) or do it manually - via decorator, via customized queryset, via custom signal or by manually calling `close_if_unusable_or_obsolete`.